# How do I draw text in my Java GUI based on an if condition in my paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have an if condition to win a game in my paintComponent and I was wondering how should I draw it to display in my Jpanel Java GUI?

```
 @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Graphics2D buffer = world.createGraphics();
        buffer.setColor(Color.black);
        buffer.fillRect(0, 0, GameConstants.WORLD_WIDTH, GameConstants.WORLD_HEIGHT);

        this.p1.drawImage(buffer);
        this.p2.drawImage(buffer);
        this.p3.drawImage(buffer);
        this.p4.drawImage(buffer);
        this.s1.drawImage(buffer);
        this.a1.drawImage(buffer);
        this.a2.drawImage(buffer);
        this.a3.drawImage(buffer);
        this.a4.drawImage(buffer);
        //g2.drawImage(this.Background,0,0,null);
        g2.drawImage(world,0,0,null);
        if (this.p1.x == 6000 && this.p2.x == 6000 && this.p3.x == 6000 && this.p4.x == 6000){
            g2.drawString("YOU WIN!!!");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Debug your code, print or inspect the values of `p1`-`p4` as they ALL must be `6000`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have previously.

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] as I can basically make it work, but there is something about your code which isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a String you must specify the coordinates.

```
g.setFont();  // set a font if you wish use -- new Font(...)
if (some condition) {
    g.drawString(str, x, y);
}
```

But it appears you are doing a number of things incorrectly.  First, you should put `super.paintComponent(g);` as your first statement in the `paintComponent` method. And you should only be painting using the graphics context supplied by `paintComponent`  Also note that

1. the coordinates must be within the bounds of the container where you are drawing, and
2. you must set the color using `g.setColor()` where the argument is from the Color class. Otherwise you are probably painting in the same default color of the container's background, so it won't be seen.

You mays also want to consider using [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) to display a winning message or any other of a variety of messages.
Also check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) on examples of painting and using `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Thank you, I still don't see anything being displayed though.

Comment: What are you painting in. The coordinates must be within the bounds of what you are drawing.  And also you must set the color using `g.setColor()` where the argument is from the Color class.  Otherwise you are probably painting in the same color, so it won't be seen.  I'm sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: it works now :)

Comment: *"I forgot to mention that."* It seems to have done the trick. Can you [edit] it into the answer for greater visibility? OP: Please accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' to the left of it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson  Done! (I should have done that without prodding.)  I also made the explanation a little clearer.  Thanks!